# Doctrine doesn't have MSSQL driver for Debian system [Ubuntu]

Tags: php, zend-framework, sql-server-2012, doctrine, debian

I am trying to connect to `MSSQL DB` using doctrine as ORM layer. I am using ubuntu and seems like **Doctrine** doesn't have **`PDODBlib`** driver. It only has `PDOSqlSrv` and `SQLSrv` support which only works in Windows system.

By the way, I am using Zend framework.

[image]

Seems like I can install third party libraries for Zend2 doctrine to support for MSSQL using: https://zfmodules.com/mabuzagu/PDODblibModule [there exists other libraries as well]. I need the same for Zend 1.

**Need help if you have already connected mssql using zend 1 doctrine.**

Comment: why downvote here?

Comment: Have you tried any generic drivers like OleDB or ODBC?

Comment: No, I did not find the supporting driver inside the driver folder. can you point me?

Comment: BTW, I am trying to use the following. https://zfmodules.com/mabuzagu/PDODblibModule